# How to make JVM to recognize certificate

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool

I've a certificate, provided by certification company.

I've installed it in my windows, but I'm not able to make it works in my jvm...

I'm using key tool to import my .cer

```
keytool -import -alias santander -file c:\nova\certificado.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass pass
```

When I check through list command

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

It appears there.

But when I'll try use the webservice that wants this certificate, I get error 403- Permission denied.

I really don't know how to work with certificate.

Comment: `403- Permission denied` is not related to certificates. Your SSL connection probably succeeded, but you have other othorization-related issues. You may need particular authorization parameters

Comment: Your SSL connection *definitely* succeeded. The 403 code was transmitted via SSL. You have another problem. @ernest_k

Comment: Just to be sure, what erro do you get when the certificate is removed from the keystore file ?

Comment: @Asoub It isn't in his keystore file. It is in his `cacerts` file, which is a truststore, and if he removes it and it isn't signed by a trusted signer he will get a PKIX path building error. Why do you ask? What is the relevance?

Comment: I'm doing call through soapUI, it really works, but when I put incorrect password in ssl configuration for my pfx file, I get 403 as well, I thhik that i'm setting it wrong in the jvm ...

Comment: You are indeed setting the password wrongly, or not at all, and this is why you get 403 'permission denied'. This has exactly nothing to do with SSL certifcates.

Comment: @user207421 this is just to check when does the problem happen.

Comment: @Asoub We know when the problem happens. It happens after the SSL handshake is complete. The 403 is transmitted over the SSL connection. If it was a certificate problem it would be a different, and earlier, exception.

Comment: I know I did something wrong. So does anyone can help me do ir right ? AS I said before, I've never worked with certificates

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong with certificates. Your SSL connection is working perfectly. I've stated that four or five times now. You did something wrong with your password.

Comment: So tell me  how to fix ?

Comment: I don't know how to fix. Nobody does, except you. You have made a password error or omission. You haven't posted the relevant code. Your expectations of magical service here are not realistic.

Comment: ok , thanks for your help, I'll remove java from my machine, Install again and ask for other how to do it right....

Comment: does anyone can tell me how to import certificate into java virtual machine for my magical expectations as @user207421 said ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your Java installation, or with importing certificates, which you have done perfectly, as you have already been told several times. or with asking others questions they cannot answer without the information you have withheld here. It has to do with transmitting your credentials correctly to the Web service you are using, by which I do not mean accepting its certificate.

Comment: I'm using Penaho to call the service, so I just put the url and xml, Pentaho using JVM, so I first I need set up my certificate in my JVM.... I did it in soapui client, It worked very well